# swiftでキーボードからの入力を取得する

Tags: swift, python

swiftでキーボードからの入力を取得したいと思っています。
pythonでは下記のようにして取得できましたがswiftではどうすればいいのでしょうか?
ちなみにswiftは`xcrun swift input.swift` としてコマンドライン上で実行します。

```
input_str = raw_input("Hello") #python2
input_str = input("Hello") #python3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python3の`input()`に近いものを実装してみました。

```
import Foundation

func input(prompt: String = "") -> String {
    print(prompt)
    fflush(__stdoutp)
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    let charset = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"\r\n")
    let str = NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    return str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(charset)
}

println(input(prompt: ">> "))
```

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24004776/1205869

```
$ xcrun swift input.swift
>> Hello
Hello
```